# Get text between a word and end of line

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I have a string of the form:

```
var str = "key0 value0
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3"
```

For a given key, I would like to get the text of the corresponding value.
So for `key1` I would like to get `value1`.

How can I extract that text from the String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would parse your text into a map:

```
var map = str.split('\n').reduce(function(m,line){
   var tokens = line.split(' ');
   m.set(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
   return m;
}, new Map);
```

which then enables simple accesses:

```
var myValue = map.get('key1');
```

```js
var str = "key0 value0\nkey1 value1\nkey2 value2\nkey3 value3";

    var map = str.split('\n').reduce(function(m,l){
       var tokens = l.split(' ');
       return m.set(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
    }, new Map);


    var myValue = map.get('key1');

document.body.textContent = ("key1 => "+ myValue);
```

---

If you've already switched to ES2015, here's a sweeter version:

```
let map = str.split('\n').reduce((m,l) => m.set(...l.split(' ')), new Map);
```